# Got an exception while running a JPQL query using Spring @Query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```
@Query("select new map(count(t.status) as allCount,sum(case when t.status='Approved' then 1 else 0 end) as approvedCount, "
        + "sum(case when t.status='Overdue'  then 1 else 0 end) as overdueCount,"
        + "sum(case when t.status='Rejected' then 1 else 0 end) as rejectedCount,"
        + "sum(case when t.status='Awaiting Approval' then 1 else 0 end) as awaitingApprovalCount,"
        + "sum(case when t.status='Not Submitted' then 1 else 0 end) as notSubmittedCount) "
        + "from Timesheet as t where t.emplId=:employeeId and (t.startDate between date_add(:startDate, interval -6 day) and date_add(:endDate,interval 6 day))"
        + "and (t.endDate between date_add(:startDate, interval -6 day) and date_add(:endDate,interval 6 day))")
```

where it throws an exception as `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException : Expecting CLOSE, found 'day' near line 1.`

Comment: As any JPQL reference would tell you ... "date_add", "interval", "day" are invalid JPQL keywords. JPQL != SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA doesn't understand this MySQL function.
So, to solve your problem, you should compute intervals outside of the query and provide intervals to the query as parameters.
And in your case, you should manage to do it since the interval doesn't rely on any data from requested tables but on known data before the query is executed since you compute the interval with `:startDate` and `:endDate` parameters :

```
 and (t.startDate between date_add(:startDate, interval -6 day)
 and date_add(:endDate,interval 6 day))+
 and (t.endDate between date_add(:startDate, interval -6 day) and  
 date_add(:endDate,interval 6 day))")
```

In your method where you call the query, you compute the dates (I have used JodaTime for the example):

```
Date computedStartDate = new DateTime(startdate).minusDay(6).toDate();
Date computedEndDate = new DateTime(endDate).plusDay(6).toDate();
...
// you create your query
//...
//you set these dates
 query.setParameter("computedStartDate",computedStartDate);
 query.setParameter("computedEndDate",computedEndDate);
// you execute your query
```

In the query you replace MySql functions by these parameterized dates.

```
@Query("select new map(count(t.status) as allCount,sum(case when t.status='Approved' then 1 else 0 end) as approvedCount, "
        + "sum(case when t.status='Overdue'  then 1 else 0 end) as overdueCount,"
        + "sum(case when t.status='Rejected' then 1 else 0 end) as rejectedCount,"
        + "sum(case when t.status='Awaiting Approval' then 1 else 0 end) as awaitingApprovalCount,"
        + "sum(case when t.status='Not Submitted' then 1 else 0 end) as notSubmittedCount) "
        + "from Timesheet as t where t.emplId=:employeeId and (t.startDate between :computedStartDate and :computedEndDate)"
        + "and (t.endDate between :computedStartDate and :computedEndDate)")
```